# Latest nexus release artifact

Tags: maven-2, nexus

I have setup a Nexus repository to store our built artifacts, third party dependencies, and home brewed shared source code headers.

I am currently using wget to retrieve the third party dependencies and shared source headers for use while building our software applications (the source for the specific applications are stored in separate git repositories).

When you use wget, you essentially have to know the exact version of the artifact that you want - you must explicitly know what the latest version number is.

Is there another way to retrieve the latest version of an artifact from the maven releases nexus repository without actually knowing what the version number is?

It would be ideal if there was a way to do this using wget instead of maven itself because I don't want to force users to install apache maven just for the purpose of downloading artifacts from nexus.

Comment: Nexus has a REST API to search for artifacts..See the docs of Nexus (Which version of Nexus do you use?)

Comment: I am using Nexus 3 OSS.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot do it by using curl only. You will need to accomplish other tasks to achieve what you want.

Here is a possibility:

You should first access to maven repository metadata file. (You will find the documentation here: http://maven.apache.org/ref/3-LATEST/maven-repository-metadata/repository-metadata.html)

For instance, let's say that you want to download the latest version of the following maven artifact from maven central:

```
groupId = javax
artifactId = javaee-api
```

Download the following file:

http://central.maven.org/maven2/javax/javaee-api/maven-metadata.xml

Its contents will be something like:

```xml
<metadata>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <versioning>
        <latest>8.0</latest>
        <release>8.0</release>
        <versions>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <version>8.0</version>
        </versions>
        <lastUpdated>20170915063942</lastUpdated>
    </versioning>
</metadata>
```

Then you will need to access the latest tag to retrieve the latest version.

Documentation says the following regarding the meaning of the latest or release tag:

```
latest  String  What the latest version in the directory is, including snapshots
release String  What the latest version in the directory is, of the releases only
```

You should find this file also in nexus repositories, and you should use something like xmllint to obtain the value you want. For instance:

```
curl http://central.maven.org/maven2/jx/javaee-api/maven-metadata.xml \
| xmllint --xpath "/metadata/versioning/latest/text()" -
```

or

```
curl http://central.maven.org/maven2/jx/javaee-api/maven-metadata.xml \
| xmllint --xpath "/metadata/versioning/release/text()" -
```

depending on what you want exactly.

After that, you can use the version information to compose the full URL of the artifact you want to download.

Hope this helps.

Cheers.

Edu.